# Is it normal that URL's are getting crawled in Screaming frog Still they have a no-follow and no-index tag on them

Tags: web-crawlers, search-engine-indexing, screaming-frog

I'm getting a lot of URL's in screaming frog where the URLs are no-follow no-index but, they are still getting crawled in screaming frog. Is it fine or should I change anything in this?

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing is normal.    Neither `noindex` nor `nofollow` should prevent crawlers such as Screaming Frog or Googlebot from crawling those pages.

When Screaming Frog encounters a `nofollow` page, it will not add the links on that page to its crawl queue.  `nofollow` doesn't prevent that page itself from being crawled.  Screaming Frog supports a configuration option called "[Follow internal or external ‘nofollow’](https://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/seo-spider/user-guide/configuration/#follow-internal-or-external-nofollow)" that would cause it to crawl all the links on `nofollow` pages. However, that configuration option is not enabled by default.

Screaming Frog is does not create a search index, so `noindex` would not normally apply to it.   Screaming frog does support a configuration option called "[respect noindex](https://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/seo-spider/user-guide/configuration/#respect-noindex)" that causes Screaming Frog not to include `noindex` URLs in its reports.  Note that that it wouldn't prevent Screaming From from crawling the URLs, it just won't report on them.   That would be similar to the way that Googlebot can crawl the URLs, just not include them in its search index.  You can enable that configuration if you desire.